# HCN reactor design

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics, chemical-engineering, rate-equation

For my diploma work, I should design a hydrogen cyanide (HCN) producing reactor.

I found that for the [BMA process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMA_process), overall

$$\ce{CH4 + NH3 -> HCN + 3 H2 \quad{} \Delta{}H_r = \pu{251 kJ / mol} }$$
Also, there is side reaction of ammonia decomposition.

the decomposition of ammonia is the rate-limiting step. So I should consider it to find the reactor volume. Besides Langmuir - Hinshelwood model, I also found power law rate to calculate the parameter manually. The expression is like this:

r = 2.27 * 10^23* exp (-21000/RT)*P(NH3)

Previously, I have used [plug-flow design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_flow_reactor_model) (PFR) equation which integrates dx/-r, where r is expressed in terms of x - concentration.

However, I do not know how to work with the previous equation, how to relate with conversion. And I am not sure about how to get the design parameter from it. **My question is how this kind of power law rate expressions with pressure instead of concentration should be used in design equations?**

Any contribution is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the units  of $r$ and of $\pu{2.27 10^{23}}$. Is $21000$ in Joules ? $\pu{10^{23}}$ is an extremely high number. Is it expressed in molecules per second and $\pu{m^3}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will lead you to the general equation. We can relate the partial pressure of a species with conversion by using a simple stoichiometric table.

---

The reaction is

$$ \ce{NH3(g) + CH4(g) -> HCN(g) + 3H2(g)} $$
$$ \ce{A(g) + B(g) -> C(g) + 3D(g)} \tag{R} $$
where we defined for convenience new letters for all the species. We concentrate on $\ce{A}$.

**1. Mole balance**

For a PFR the volume needed to achieve a conversion $X_\ce{A}$ is
\begin{equation}
  V = \int_0^{X_\mathrm{A}} \frac{F_\mathrm{A0} \; \mathrm{d}X_\ce{A}}
                                  {-r_\ce{A}(X_\ce{A})} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $F_\mathrm{A0}$ is the inlet molar flow rate of species $\ce{A}$ in $\pu{mol s^-1}$

**2. Rate law**

We have a power law in the form of
$$ -r_\ce{A} = kp_\ce{A} \tag{2} $$

**3. Stoichiometry**

We set up a stoichiometric table for reaction $\ce{R}$ in terms of the molar flows. For a general species $j$ in a reaction where $\ce{A}$ is the limiting reagent, the molar flow rate of species $j$ is
$$ F_{j} = F_\mathrm{A0} (\Theta_j + \nu_j X_\ce{A}) \tag{3} $$
where $\Theta_j = F_{j0}/F_\mathrm{A0}$ is the molar relation of species $j$ with respect to $\ce{A}$ at the entrance of the reactor, and $\nu_j$ is the stoichiometric coefficient of species $j$.

For the reaction to take place, we need the presence of $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$. Considering that there are no products at the reactor inlet, application of Eq. (3) to reaction $\ce{R}$ gives
\begin{align}
   F_\ce{A} &=  F_\mathrm{A0}(1 - X_\ce{A}) \tag{4} \\
   F_\ce{B} &=  F_\mathrm{A0}(\Theta_\ce{B} - X_\ce{A}) \tag{5} \\
   F_\ce{C} &=  F_\mathrm{A0} X_\ce{A} \tag{6} \\
   F_\ce{D} &= 3F_\mathrm{A0} X_\ce{A} \tag{7} \\
\end{align}
where the total molar flow rate is
\begin{align}
  F_\ce{T} &= \sum_j F_j \\
  F_\ce{T} &= F_\mathrm{A0}(1 - X_\ce{A}) + F_\mathrm{A0}(\Theta_\ce{B} - X_\ce{A}) +
              F_\mathrm{A0} X_\ce{A} + 3F_\mathrm{A0} X_\ce{A} \\
  F_\ce{T} &= F_\mathrm{A0}(1 - X_\ce{A} + \Theta_\ce{B} - X_\ce{A} +
                            X_\ce{A} + 3X_\ce{A}) \\
  F_\ce{T} &= F_\mathrm{A0}(1 + \Theta_\ce{B}  + 2X_\ce{A}) \tag{9} \\
\end{align}

Remembering that the partial pressure of species $j$ is given by
$$ p_j = y_j p = \frac{F_j}{F_\ce{T}}p \tag{10}$$
we combine Eqs. (4), (9), and (10) so that
\begin{align}
  \require{cancel}
  p_\ce{A} &= \frac{\cancel{F_\mathrm{A0}}(1 - X_\ce{A})}
                   {\cancel{F_\mathrm{A0}}(1 + \Theta_\ce{B}  + 2X_\ce{A})}p \\
  p_\ce{A} &= \left(\frac{1 - X_\ce{A}}{1 + \Theta_B  + 2X_\ce{A}}\right)p \tag{11}
\end{align}

**4. Design equation**

Combining Eqs. (1), (2), and (11) gives the final result
\begin{equation}
  \boxed{V = \int_0^{X_\mathrm{A}} \frac{F_\mathrm{A0} \; \mathrm{d}X_\ce{A}}
  {k\left(\dfrac{1 - X_\ce{A}}{1 + \Theta_\ce{B} + 2X_\ce{A}}\right)p}} \tag{12}
\end{equation}

---

**References**

An excellent explanation for stoichiometry for liquid-phase and gas-phase reactive systems  can be read at Chapter 3 of:

- **Elements of Chemical Reaction Engineering**, H. S. Fogler, 5th ed., Prentice Hall (2016).